# How can I create Content Boxes in HTML Paste Email

Tags: marketing-cloud

Need to have dynamic content in HTML Paste Email, How can I create Content Boxes to achieve this.

As per ExactTarget documentation

> Content boxes apear automatically in the email editor if you use one
>   of the provided email layouts for your template, but you can also
>   include them in your HTML paste templates. Content boxes do not
>   automatically appear in the email editor if you are making an HTML
>   paste email. http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_overview/content_boxes/#How_To_Store_a_Content_Box.c2.a0for_Future_Use

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I posted this question after doing little effort at my end so apologies..

Posting the answer, just for those who may want to know  this as well.

To insert dynamic content in your HTML paste emails, you need to create a template and select HTML paste. Paste your HTML and select area where you want to insert dynamic content and insert->content area.... name the area and insert.

Now create email and select template based rather HTML paste and select the template you created. When it loaded you can see your content area created and insert your dynamic content (already created).

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Inside an HTML Paste Template you can use the custom tag of type content.

```
<custom type="content" name="Content Box Name Here">
```

This would then give you the content editor popup when you use the template.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use HTML Paste emails and retrieve already created content areas, you can achieve this with the use of AMPScript.  You cannot retrieve Dynamic Content areas but you can use the same logic with AMPScript to dynamically retrieve those content areas you need.

Example and info is provided below.  Let me know if you have any questions.  Thanks!

To Simply retrieve a content area by the Content Area ID, use this:

```
%%=ContentArea("14")=%%
```

If you want to dynamically retrieve a content area in an HTML Paste email, you can set this up similar to the below:

```
%%[ 
Var @Gender 
Set @Gender = [Gender]
]%% 

%%[IF @Gender == "Male" THEN]%% 
%%=ContentArea("14")=%%
%%[ELSEIF @Gender == "Female" THEN]%% 
%%=ContentArea("15")=%% 
%%[ELSE]%% 
%%=ContentArea("16")=%% 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

[ContentArea() AMPScript Documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#ContentArea)